# S3 Multi-part Upload fails on completion after parts have successfully been completed

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload data generated on the fly from memory to S3.

Here's the code for actually uploading the parts:

```
UploadPartRequest partReq = new UploadPartRequest()
    .withBucketName( this.getBucket() )
    .withKey( this.getKey() )
    .withUploadId( uploadId )
    .withPartNumber( partNumber )
    .withPartSize( partSize )
    .withInputStream( is )
    .withGeneralProgressListener( (ProgressEvent e) -> {
            log.info( "{} {} {} {} {} {} bytes transferred",
            this.getBucket(), this.getKey(), uploadId, partNumber,
            e.getEventType(), e.getBytesTransferred() );
    });
UploadPartResult partRes = this.getClient().uploadPart( partReq );
```

After all the parts have been uploaded following lines appear in my logs which I presume to mean that all of the upload parts were all successfully uploaded.

```
1 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT 
2 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT 
3 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT 
4 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT 
5 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT 
6 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT 
7 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT 
8 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT 
9 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT 
10 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT
11 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT
12 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT
13 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT
14 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT
15 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT
17 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT
16 TRANSFER_PART_COMPLETED_EVENT
```

There were many occurrences of this following line too for each of the upload part while they are still uploading which tells me that it is indeed was sending data for those uploads.

```
REQUEST_BYTE_TRANSFER_EVENT 8192 bytes transferred
```

And here's the code I'm using to finally complete the entire upload process.

```
CompleteMultipartUploadRequest cmpur = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest()
    .withBucketName( this.getBucket() )
    .withKey( this.getKey() )
    .withUploadId( result.getUploadId() )
    .withPartETags( new ArrayList<>( this.getUploadPartResults() ) )
    .withGeneralProgressListener((e) -> {
        log.info( "{} {} {} {} bytes transferred",
        this.getBucket(), this.getKey(),
        e.getEventType(), e.getBytesTransferred() );
    });
this.getClient().completeMultipartUpload( cmpur );
```

Right after sending a request to complete the entire multi-part uploads, I'm getting the following in the logs:

```
REQUEST_CONTENT_LENGTH_EVENT
CLIENT_REQUEST_STARTED_EVENT
HTTP_REQUEST_STARTED_EVENT
HTTP_REQUEST_COMPLETED_EVENT
CLIENT_REQUEST_FAILED_EVENT
```

And then the thread hangs in there.

I presume CLIENT_REQUEST_FAILED_EVENT means the entire upload failed. What am I missing?

I tried increasing the part size so there will be just a single uploaded part for the entire multi-part upload and it was successful. If the total parts is more than 1 then it fails.

Here's the logs for successful upload when it's only having a single part.

```
REQUEST_CONTENT_LENGTH_EVENT 0 bytes transferred
CLIENT_REQUEST_STARTED_EVENT 0 bytes transferred
HTTP_REQUEST_STARTED_EVENT 0 bytes transferred
HTTP_REQUEST_COMPLETED_EVENT 0 bytes transferred
RESPONSE_CONTENT_LENGTH_EVENT 0 bytes transferred
HTTP_RESPONSE_STARTED_EVENT 0 bytes transferred
RESPONSE_BYTE_TRANSFER_EVENT 309 bytes transferred
HTTP_RESPONSE_COMPLETED_EVENT 0 bytes transferred
CLIENT_REQUEST_SUCCESS_EVENT 0 bytes transferred
REQUEST_BYTE_TRANSFER_EVENT 135 bytes transferred
```

Perhaps, what else can I put in the logs to get something more to see what went wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that it was because of the fact that my parts were actually less than the required minimum size which is 5MB.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/qfacts.html

I've been to that page several times and yet I overlooked it. It's really easy to overlook. The logs didn't help either.