# How to get list of failed parts on s3 multipart upload

Tags: go, amazon-s3, minio

sometimes after completing the multipart upload request with s3 client, I get this error:

```
InvalidPart: One or more of the specified parts could not be found. The part may not have been uploaded, or the specified entity tag may not match the part's entity tag.\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: 15BACD159D8498B7
```

there is no error on any `s3client.UploadPart(partInput)` calls, so the parts are uploaded well, and my `completedParts` slice is complete and all of the `s3.CompletedPart` are in it.

How can I identify those "One or more" parts that s3 can't find and re-upload them?

Comment: Not sure if this relates, but have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49151642/13860

Comment: @Flimzy hmmm, actually my parts are smaller than 5mb, but I changed the minimum limit in my minio server, so it shouldn't raise a problem :-?